# What's the PostgreSQL equivalent of SQL Servfer's CONTEXT_INFO?

Tags: postgresql, logging, rdbms, audit, dml

In relation to my other question ["What’s the best way to audit log DELETEs?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695817/whats-the-best-way-to-audit-log-deletes).  What's the PostgreSQL equivalent of `CONTEXT_INFO`?

I want to log deletes using a trigger, but since I'm not using the database user as my app's logical user, I cannot log the `CURRENT_USER` from the trigger code as the user who deleted the record. But for `INSERT` and `UPDATE` it is possible to log the record changes from trigger since you can just add a user field in the record, say `inserted_by` and `last_updated_by`, and use these fields to log to audit table.

Comment: Please remember that not everybody knows MSSQL, so saying "what's the equivalent of XXX" is not really well stated question - explain what CONTEXT_INFO is, and what it is used for. Then - somebody with Pg skills can check how to get given functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.postgres.cz/index.php/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks_II#Any_other_session_variables

PostgreSQL provides more variants, please, look to this site.

Comment: Link-only answers are bad. What if that site goes offline?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is outdated.

In recent versions of postgresql (since 9.3 or 9.4 I think), one can set / retrieve config variables are only alive for the current session [or transaction]. [Documentation Reference](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html)

example of setting a *session* variable:

```
hal=# select set_config('myvar.foo', 'bar', false);
 set_config 
------------
 bar
(1 row)

hal=# select current_setting('myvar.foo');
 current_setting 
-----------------
 bar
(1 row)
```

It is possible to use the function `current_setting` as one would use other set returning functions.

example:

```
create table customers (id int);
insert into customers values (1), (2), (3), (4);

select c.*, s.*
from customers c
left join current_setting('myvar.foo') s
       on c.id = length(s)
```