# Postgresql equivalent to SQL Server CONTEXT_INFO

Tags: postgresql

In SQL Server, there is a built-in function `CONTEXT_INFO()` to read the value of `CONTEXT_INFO` variable.

```
SET CONTEXT_INFO 0; // set
SELECT CONTEXT_INFO(); // Get
```

I want to do the same thing for PostgreSQL with Session scope. How can I do SET and GET with session scope ?

I even tried to refer [What's the PostgreSQL equivalent of MSSQL's CONTEXT_INFO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696200/whats-the-postgresql-equivalent-of-mssqls-context-info) and hence https://postgres.cz/wiki/PostgreSQL_SQL_Tricks_II#Any_other_session_variables but still couldn't make it work. Do I need to configure something to make this work ?

Comment: Duplicate of [What's the PostgreSQL equivalent of MSSQL's CONTEXT\_INFO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696200/whats-the-postgresql-equivalent-of-mssqls-context-info)

Comment: @KaushikNayak That question has no useful answers. It also doesn't address the "session scope" part.

Comment: @melpomene That's true, kindly help to re-open this question by clicking on "reopen"

Comment: @melpomene : Ok, I've voted to reopen.